# My Batis Type conversion error in insert parameter

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, ibatis

I am new to mybatis. I have a property in my class with java BigInteger. relevant mysql field type is BigInt. When i am going to insert a record to database with xml configuration file it gives an exception like `'There was no TypeHandler found for parameter id'`.

My xml insert query is,

```
INSERT INTO xX_ (
    id, date, name, connection)
    VALUES (
    #{id}, #{date}, #{name}, #{connection}
)
```

Please help me to fix this without changing the type on the DTO class.

Comment: post your mapper file or interface

Comment: What does your question have to do with spring?

Comment: This is my mapper. <insert id="createDetail" useGeneratedKeys="true"
  parameterType="myDetail">
   INSERT INTO xX_ (
     id, date, name, connection)
     VALUES (
     #{id}, #{date}, #{name}, #{connection}
   )
<selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="java.lang.Long" order="AFTER" >
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
</selectKey>
</insert>

Comment: for which field you are getting error?

Answer (score 1):

Please, look here: http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers

To use BigInteger and BigInt you have to write a custom typeHandler, like this:

```
// ExampleTypeHandler.java
@MappedTypes(BigInteger.class)
public class BigIntegerTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<BigInteger> {

  //implement all methods
}
```

config your config.xml like this:

```
<!-- mybatis-config.xml -->
<typeHandlers>
  <typeHandler handler="your.packadge.BigIntegerTypeHandler"/>
</typeHandlers>
```

It must help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id")
void createDetail(myDetail md);


<insert id="createDetail" parameterType="myDetail">
    INSERT INTO xX_
       ( id,
         `date`,
         `name`,
         `connection`)
    VALUES ( #{id,     javaType=BigInteger,    jdbcType=BIGINT},
             #{date},
             #{name},
             #{connection} )

    <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="java.math.BigInteger">
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
    </selectKey>
</insert>
```

Try different javaType, resultType and [jdbcType](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/apidocs/reference/org/apache/ibatis/type/JdbcType.html). For example, javaType=java.math.BigInteger javaType=Long, javaType=java.lang.Long, jdbcType=NUMERIC, jdbcType=DECIMAL, resultType="java.lang.Long".

parameterType="myDetail" must be equal to Class name, but not the name of instance of a class. If your class name is com.yourcompany.MyDetail and instance name is myDetail, try to use parameterType="MyDetail" or parameterType="com.yourcompany.MyDetail"

See also ["Table 5.2 MySQL Types to Java Types for ResultSet.getObject()"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html).

```
MySQL Type Name: BIGINT[(M)] [UNSIGNED]

Returned as Java Class: java.lang.Long, if UNSIGNED java.math.BigInteger
```

Answer (score 0):

Where i used to work we used MyBatis with Spring.

We used to do the declarations as follows
Note the userId that we set as jdbcType = VARCHAR which the DB driver then converted correctly to BigInt or whatever we were using.

I think we used Long in the Object in system.

```
<delete id="deleteJob" parameterType="com.beans.JobDetailVO">
    UPDATE JOBS.JOB
    SET
        DO_NOT_USE=#{doNotUse}
    WHERE
        JOB_ID=#{postedJobID} and USER_ID=#{userID,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
</delete>
```

As for inserts we did the following

```
 <insert id="insertJobDetail" parameterType="com.beans.JobDetailVO">

        INSERT INTO JOBS.JOB
        (
        JOB_ID,
        RECRUITER_TYPE_ID,
        USER_DETAIL_ID,
        HIDE_RECRUITER_INFO,
        TITLE, ....
        )
        VALUES (
        #{jobID,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{recruiterTypeID ,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{userDetailID ,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{hideRecruiterInfo ,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{jobTitle ,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
            .....
        )
        <selectKey resultType="java.lang.Long" statementType="STATEMENT" keyProperty="JobID" order="BEFORE">SELECT
            JOBS.S_JOB.NEXTVAL AS JOBID FROM DUAL
        </selectKey>

    </insert>
```